# Sortable column with custom taxonomy in custom posts type

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created custom column in my custom post type. This column shows the custom taxonomy. This is the code:

```
     function custom_MY_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_column( $column, $post_id ) {
        switch ( $column ) {

            case 'MY_CUSTOM_COLUMN';
                $terms = get_the_term_list( $post_id , 'MY_CUSTOM_COLUMN' , '' , ',' , '' );
                if ( is_string( $terms ) )
                    echo $terms;
                else
                    _e( '-', 'your_text_domain' );
                break;    
        }
    }
```

Now I need this column to be sortable alphabetically so I created this code:

```
// Register the column as sortable
function x_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['MY_CUSTOM_COLUMN'] = 'x';

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-MY_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_sortable_columns', 'x_column_register_sortable' );
```

but this isn't working. How can I makes this column works correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to sort by "x" but WordPress doesn't know what that is. So you either need to sort by something WP understands like "title":

```
$columns['MY_CUSTOM_COLUMN'] = 'title';
```

Otherwise you need "x" to actually do something like such:

```
function my_custom_query_sort( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');

    if ( 'x' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'SOMETHING CUSTOM' );
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_query_sort' );
```

But that's not the only issue...You mention the column is a custom taxonomy. There isn't any core function in WordPress to sort posts by taxonomy. Not to mention that each post could have multiple terms assigned to them.

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong... There is no option to sort taxonomy alphabetically in column?